# Based on the value in one column change the value in another column across group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server.

I have a table:

```
Group   id     DEPT     marks         
--------------------------------------
 A      001      CS      P                  
 A      002     ECE      P  
 A      003     MC       P  
 B      561     CS       F  
 B      781     IT       F  
 C      789     CS       F  
 C      003     CS       F
```

If a department has failure 'new column ' dept contain Failures should get value 'F'
Here CS  contains F so the entire dept should get a value 'F' in deptcontainsfailures column
where as other departments
 eg:- ECE contains oly P , so it has 'P' in Ddeptcontainfailures
I am trying to do this select statement

```
SELECT group,  
      id,  
    dept,  
      marks,  
CASE WHEN marks='P' THEN  'P'   
            ELSE 'F'  
            END Ddeptcontainfailure  
 FROM Depttable
```

The output I am getting

---

```
Group   id     DEPT     marks            Ddeptcontainfailures
-----------------------------------------------------
 A      001     CS       P                  p   
 A      002     ECE      P                  P  
 A      003     MC       P                  P  
 B      561     CS       F                  F  
 B      781     IT       F                  F  
 C      789     CS       P                  p  
 C      003     CS       P                  p
```

How can I achieve that?

Desired output

---

```
Group   id     DEPT     marks      Ddeptcontainfailures
-----------------------------------------------------
 A      001     CS       P          F       
 A      002     ECE      P          P  
 A      003     MC       P          P  
 B      561     CS       F          F  
 B      781     IT       F          F  
 C      789     CS       P          F  
 C      003     CS       P          F
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MIN with partitioning to do this. This works because you have only two values for marks. If your real data contains other values you could use a case expression inside the MIN function.

```
declare @Something table
(
    MyGroup char(1)
    , id char(3)
    , DEPT varchar(3)
    , marks char(1)
)

insert @Something values
('A', '001', 'CS', 'P')
, ('A', '002', 'ECE', 'P')
, ('A', '003', 'MC', 'P')
, ('B', '561', 'CS', 'F')
, ('B', '781', 'IT', 'F')
, ('C', '789', 'CS', 'F')
, ('C', '003', 'CS', 'F')

select s.*
    , min(marks) over(partition by DEPT)
from @Something s
order by s.MyGroup
    , s.id
    , s.DEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

My friend there are multiple ways to do this

One of the easiest ways is to use subqueries

```
SELECT GROUP
      ,ID
      ,DEPT
      ,MARKS
      ,CASE WHEN DP.DEPT IS NULL THEN 'P' ELSE 'F' END AS DDEPTCONTAINFAILURE
FROM DEPTTABLE DT
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DEPT 
            FROM DEPTTABLE
            WHERE MARKS LIKE 'F') DP 
ON (DT.DEPT = DP.DEPT)
```

If you want to know a department is have a failing value you will first have to know which one. then you can use a flag, in my case i am using CASE WHEN DP.DEPT IS NULL to know

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative solution with `cte` structure:

```
create table #temp
(
    MyGroup char(1)
    , id char(3)
    , DEPT varchar(3)
    , marks char(1)
)

insert #temp values
('A', '001', 'CS', 'P')
, ('A', '002', 'ECE', 'P')
, ('A', '003', 'MC', 'P')
, ('B', '561', 'CS', 'F')
, ('B', '781', 'IT', 'F')
, ('C', '789', 'CS', 'F')
, ('C', '003', 'CS', 'F')

;with cte as (
select distinct t.DEPT
from #temp t
where t.marks = 'F'
)
select t.*, (case when t.DEPT in (select DEPT from cte) then 'F' else 'T' end)
from #temp t
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
SELECT [group],  
      id,  
    Depttable.dept,  
      marks,  
CASE WHEN isnull(failures, 0) = 0 THEN  'P'   
            ELSE 'F'  
            END Ddeptcontainfailure  
 FROM Depttable
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    select count(*) as failures, alias.dept
    from Depttable alias
    where marks='f'
    group by alias.dept
 ) X on x.dept = Depttable.dept
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group,  
      id,  
    dept,  
      marks,  
CASE WHEN 'F' in (select marks from Depttable di where di.marks=do.marks)    THEN  'F'   
            ELSE 'P'  
            END Ddeptcontainfailure  
 FROM Depttable do
```

**or**

```
SELECT group,  
      id,  
    dept,  
      marks,  
(select min(marks) from Depttable di where di.marks=do.marks) Ddeptcontainfailure  
 FROM Depttable do
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column Ddeptcontainfailures you will only have 2 values, so you can use this query

```
    declare @temp table(Grou varchar(10), id varchar(10), Dept varchar(10), marks varchar(10))

    insert into @temp (Grou, id, dept, marks)
    select 'A', '001' ,'CS' , 'P'
    union
    select 'A', '002' ,'ECE', 'P'
     union
    select 'A', '003' ,'MC', 'P'
     union
    select 'B', '561' ,'CS', 'F'
     union
    select 'B', '781' ,'IT', 'F'
     union
    select 'C', '789' ,'CS', 'F'
     union
    select 'C', '003' ,'CS', 'F'


    select t.Grou, t.id, t.Dept, t.marks, (select top 1 B.marks from @temp B where B.Dept = t.Dept order by B.marks) as Ddeptcontainfailures

    from @temp t
```

When sorting by  B.marks, "F" will always come first in the results